# Show elements on click instead of on CSS :hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, html-lists

Currently I use `:hover` in my CSS to display my nested lists in `.wrapper1` elements. I want to make it so that they open on click instead of on hover.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
$(function() {
  // whenever we hover over a menu item that has a submenu
  $('li.parent').on('click', function() {
    var $menuItem = $(this),
        $submenuWrapper = $('> .wrapper', $menuItem);

    // grab the menu item's position relative to its positioned parent
    var menuItemPos = $menuItem.position();

    // place the submenu in the correct position relevant to the menu item
    $submenuWrapper.css({
      top: menuItemPos.top,
      left: menuItemPos.left + Math.round($menuItem.outerWidth() * 0.75)
    });
  });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/72tnxh45/2/

Below is css which can affect to display all sublinks.

```
.wrapper1 li:hover > .wrapper1 {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: For starters, you need to import jQuery. Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72tnxh45/2/)

Comment: in my code i include jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $(".wrapper ul li").click(function(){
       //do what ever you want to do with li
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look attached snippet.

There are made some change in jqyery code and css also.

```js
$(function() {
  // whenever we hover over a menu item that has a submenu
  $('li.parent').on('click', function() {
       if($(this).children(".wrapper").attr('style')=='display: block;'){
          $(this).children(".wrapper").css('display','none');

    }else{
                  $(this).children(".wrapper").css('display','block');

      }
     
   });
  
  
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

li {
  position: static;
}
li .wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}
li:hover > .wrapper {
  //display: block;
  
}

li:

ul {
  margin: 1em;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

li {
  padding: 1em;
}
li ul {
  margin: 0;
}
li .wrapper {
  cursor: auto;
}
li .wrapper li {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
li:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #0E8CE0;
}
li:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #0064B3;
}
li.parent {
  background: #00B99B;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   

    
    
    
  

    <div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>Abc</li>
    <li>Def</li>
    <li>Ghi</li>
    <li>Jkl</li>
    <li class="parent">Mno >
      <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
          <li>Abc</li>
          <li>Def</li>
          <li>Ghi</li>
          <li>Jkl</li>
          <li class="parent">Mno >
            <div class="wrapper">
              <ul>
                <li>Abc</li>
                <li>Def</li>
                <li>Ghi</li>
                <li>Jkl</li>
                <li>Mno</li>
                <li>Pqr</li>
                <li>Stu</li>
                <li>Vw</li>
                <li>Xyz</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>Pqr</li>
          <li>Stu</li>
          <li>Vw</li>
          <li>Xyz</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>Pqr</li>
    <li>Stu</li>
    <li>Vw</li>
    <li>Xyz</li>
    <li class="parent">Abc >
      <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
          <li>Abc</li>
          <li>Def</li>
          <li>Ghi</li>
          <li>Jkl</li>
          <li>Mno</li>
          <li>Pqr</li>
          <li>Stu</li>
          <li>Vw</li>
          <li>Xyz</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>Def</li>
    <li>Ghi</li>
    <li>Jkl</li>
    <li>Mno</li>
    <li>Pqr</li>
    <li>Stu</li>
    <li>Vw</li>
    <li>Xyz</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it works for me just facing an issue with position of child list.and if i add my code for position it will not close clicked list.